# multiple errors while launching a multirobot navigation

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

*I'm very sorry to post such a vague question, but I'm not sure what is the cause of this and what title would fit. Any suggestion will be taken into consideration.*

I am running ROS Melodic and I'm very close to deploying a multirobot navigation in a provided map.
After setting all the parameters and remaps for AMCL and move_base and launching to Rviz, the robots get spawned and localized correctely. Every [topic](https://pastebin.com/8BP14vn9) is in its correct namespace and the [rqt_graph](https://imgur.com/a/depYog3) and [tf_tree](https://imgur.com/a/8vpqLWF) (links to pastebin and imgur).

When I launch the main file, no warns or errors are shown, unless I send a goal to any robot. These are the recurring errors that I get, meaning that they continuosly get logged. The sender is `robot_1/move_base`, debugged using rqt_console:

```
[ERROR] [1573749493.401459619, 262.154000000]: Extrapolation Error: Lookup would require extrapolation into the future.  Requested time 262.139000000 but the latest data is at time 262.110000000, when looking up transform from frame [robot_1/odom] to frame [map]

[ERROR] [1573749493.401504953, 262.154000000]: Global Frame: robot_1/odom Plan Frame size 70: map

[ WARN] [1573749493.401533682, 262.154000000]: Could not transform the global plan to the frame of the controller
[ERROR] [1573749493.401555288, 262.154000000]: Could not get local plan
```

**The navigation doesn't fail**: in fact, the robot still moves and slowly (slower than usual) reaches his goal, sometimes attempting more recovery manuevers than usual.

I won't post unnecessary code because I don't want this question to get too long, eventually I'll add them by editing the question if required.

Notice that **I'm running everything locally**: no real robots involved, no communication between computers. I've seen some questions regarding the extrapolation error that were solved by adjusting some parameters in the network configuration, but this is not my case.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/337670/multiple-errors-while-launching-a-multirobot-navigation/) by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-11-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out the cause by myself:

- AMCL `base_frame_id` was set to
  `robot_1/base_footprint` while it
  should've been `base_link`.
- `local_costmap/global_frame` was set to
  `odom`, should've been `map`

---

Originally posted by [davidem](https://answers.ros.org/users/47142/davidem/) with karma: 83 on 2019-11-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1